# Custom skins in MineCraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Today I changed my skin five times and after that it wouldn't let me change my skin again! I want to pick a different skin because the skin I have currently doesn't look that good. Did I do something wrong or is it Minecraft?

Comment: Are you using the Pocket Edition or the PC version of Minecraft? Can you show us the error message it gives you?

Comment: I've changed my skin more than 5 times in a day. May just be the servers lagging, but it's hard to say without knowing what you're actually doing. You could try fully logging out and back in.

Answer (score 3):

There are limits for contacting the Mojang servers for same thing over and over. This apply for basic getting of info about player (getting UUID, nick, etc) and also for skins, capes and other info.

Be aware that if you (or the server you play on) ask too often for your new skin, the next connections will be refused by Mojang servers for some time.

If you changed it more times in small time window, Mojang servers could consider you as attacker or spammer. Waiting some time should fix this problem, try it the next day(after 24 hours) and you should be good.

If there are more issues after that time, then you can always try to contact Mojang [Support](https://help.mojang.com/).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you have to head on over to the minecraft website and log in and then select change your skin than you have to download the skin you just made and drag it to the minecraft website, choose your settings, and you're done. of course there is a limit to how many times you can do this.

Comment: If you read the post they said they did already change their skin several times.  So the only thing you got right is your last sentence, which is the same as and already given answer therefore you've added nothing useful